# Scrapy Splash click on link with javascript href

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using Scrapy Splash to scrape a page that has an element like this:

Page 1 of 349 

 |
1
|
2
|
3
|
4
|
5
|
6
|
7
|
8
|
9
|
10
|

Next 

›

I want to 'click' the anchor with the text 'Next', and have the javascript execute to fetch the next page.

This is what my scraper looks like:

```
script = """
    function main(splash)
        splash:init_cookies(splash.args.cookies)
        assert(splash:go(splash.args.url))
        splash:wait(0.5)
        local element = splash:select('div.result-content-columns div.result-title')
        local bounds = element:bounds()
        element:mouse_click{x=bounds.width/2, y=bounds.height/2}

         return {
            cookies = splash:get_cookies(),
            html = splash:html()
            }
    end
"""

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
   custom_settings = {
                'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES' : {
                            'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
                            'scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
                            'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
                            'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
                            'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
                            },

               'SPLASH_URL': 'http://192.168.59.103:8050',

               'SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES': {
                        'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
                        },

                'DUPEFILTER_CLASS':  'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter',

                'HTTPCACHE_STORAGE': 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage',
                }


    def star_requests(self):
          yield SplashRequest(url=some_url, meta={'cookiejar': 1},
                                callback=self.parse,
                                cookies={'store_language':'en'},
                                endpoint='render.html',
                                args={'wait': 5},
                            )

    def parse(self, response):
           self.extract_data_from_page(response)

            href = response.xpath('//div[@class="paging"]/p/a[contains(text(),"Next")]/@href')
            if href:
                new_url = href.extract_first()
                yield SplashRequest(new_url, self.parse,
                                    cookies={'store_language':'en'},
                                    endpoint='execute', args={'lua_source': self.script})
```

The Lua script is incorrect (I copied it from an unrelated example). My question is that how do I pass the required args to the Lua script, so that the javascript is run?

Comment: Are you asking about how to pass additional arguments into the Lua script? Or about how to write the Lua script to click a link?

Comment: @malberts I want to pass the javascript `javascript:doSubmit('frmRow',1,0)` as an argument to the Lua script, and then get the Lua script to execute it (i.e. simulating a  'click') and then return the new page as html, in the `return` statement in the Lua script.

Comment: Let me just confirm: you want to pass in another argument: `args={..., 'javascript': 'doSubmit...'}` and then access that value in the Lua script. Then inside the Lua script it must end up running `doSubmit('frmRow',1,0)`?

Comment: Also, does it really need to an argument? I.e. do you plan on passing in other Javascript snippets too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass additional arguments ([docs](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-ref.html#splash-args)) to the Lua script by adding the values to the SplashRequest's `args`:

```
javascript = "doSubmit('frmRow',1,0)"

yield SplashRequest(new_url, self.parse,
                    cookies={'store_language':'en'},
                    endpoint='execute',
                    args={'lua_source': self.script, 'javascript': javascript})
```

Inside the Lua script you can get the value in `args` and execute the Javascript with [`runjs`](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-ref.html#splash-runjs):

```
function main(splash, args)
    -- ...

    -- Get the argument here:
    local javascript = args.javascript

    -- Run the JS:
    assert(splash:runjs(javascript))

    return {
        html = splash:html()
    }
end
```